# How do I add users and their associated devices to a Dynamic group in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, membership

I would like to see if there is a way to create a Dynamic Group in Azure with expressions that would automatically populate the group with user names, and, any device that is associated with that user. Is this possible in Azure?

I have seen articles stating it may be possible in Configuration Manager however nothing that shows how to complete the creation of the group.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

•   Users and devices cannot be in the same group according to the architecture and given provisions in Azure AD and Intune. Dynamic group can be either user based, or device based but you can't mix both users and devices in the same group.

•   Though, according to your query, you can get a list of the devices and their associated primary users for those devices through a powershell script as below. Through the output of this script, you can manually create the groups according to your requirements.

```
#Get All Windows 10 Intune Managed Devices for the Tenant
$Devices = Get-Win10IntuneManagedDevice

 Foreach ($Device in $Devices) {

    Write-Host "Device name:" $device."deviceName" -ForegroundColor Cyan
    $IntuneDevicePrimaryUser = Get-IntuneDevicePrimaryUser -deviceId $Device.id
#Check if there is a Primary user set on the device already
    if($IntuneDevicePrimaryUser -eq $null){

        Write-Host "No Intune Primary User Id set for Intune Managed Device" $Device."deviceName" -f Red

    }
```

Please refer to the below links for official documentation: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/groups-dynamic-membership

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureaddeviceregisteredowner?view=azureadps-2.0